# Combining draggable and sortable leads to css height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

When I drag from one box to another the 'ul.box' class height is too tall sometimes, here's my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/akjfnkfd/

Here's an example which can be reproduced by dragging list items from one box to another, the bottom green on the bar box sticking out is wrong

[image]

I've tried to set height: auto but then the ul disappears completely

```
day_containers.droppable({
    accept: ".box-container",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);
        $(dropped).detach().css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            height: auto  /* <---- doesn't fix my issue */
        }).appendTo(droppedOn);
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem arises due to jQuery draggable/droppable automatically adding inline styles to certain elements (height and width for example). To solve your problem you could either modify only the height with something like `ui.helper.first().css({height: ''});` or simply remove the inline styles all together with something like `ui.helper.first().removeAttr('style');` and just add it to `day_containers.droppable` like so:

***jQuery***

```
day_containers.droppable({
    accept: ".box-container",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);

        //remove inline styles
        ui.helper.first().removeAttr('style');

        $(dropped).detach().css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
        }).appendTo(droppedOn);
    },
    over: function (event, elem) {
        $(this).addClass("over");
    },
    out: function (event, elem) {
        $(this).removeClass("over");
    }
});
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akjfnkfd/1/)